# MVC CSV File Download + Project Awesome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently using [project awesome](http://awesome.codeplex.com) to pop a form which asks for an account number.

I take the number and generate a csv file and send it to the browser:

```
string billcsv = "account_ref,line1,line2,line3"

var VIRFile = File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(billcsv), "text/csv", "billfor" + accnumber+ ".csv")

return Json(VIRFile);
```

I would like the end user to prompted to save the csv file but cannot figure out who to.

Should I create the CSV file on disk first then pass the url to the file to the success function and use window.open(url) or is it possible to use javascript to recreate the file from the json result?

Json Result:

> {"FileContents":[65,99,99,111,117,110,116,95,82,69,70,44,73,78,86,79,73,67,69,95,84,89,80,69,44,73,78,86,79,73,67,69,95,82,69,70,44,81,84,89,95,79,82,68,69,82,44,83,69,82,86,73,67,69,95,84,69,88,84,44,85,78,73,84,95,80,82,73,67,69,44,83,69,82,86,73,67,69,95,65,77,79,85,78,84,13,10,114,114,114,44,73,110,118,111,105,99,101,44,86,73,82,49,48,50,44,49,44,83,116,97,114,83,104,105,112,32,32,79,110,101,13,10,44,76,79,65,32,45,32,32,109,116,114,115,13,10,44,71,82,84,32,45,71,84,44,48,44,48,44,48,13,10,114,114,114,44,73,110,118,111,105,99,101,44,86,73,82,49,48,50,44,50,44,66,111,97,116,32,84,114,97,110,115,102,101,114,115,32,72,105,114,101,32,67,104,97,114,103,101,44,50,53,48,46,48,48,44,53,48,48,46,48,48,13,10,114,114,114,44,73,110,118,111,105,99,101,44,86,73,82,49,48,50,44,51,44,66,101,114,116,104,105,110,103,32,32,82,70,65,32,47,32,77,111,68,44,51,53,48,46,48,48,44,49,48,53,48,46,48,48,13,10],"ContentType":"text/csv","FileDownloadName":"billfor123.csv"}

Answer (score 11):

First of all don't use AJAX for downloading files. Use a normal form submission or an anchor pointing to the controller action which will serve the file. And then in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Download(string accnumber)
{
    string billcsv = "account_ref,line1,line2,line3";
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(billcsv);
    string filename = "billfor" + accnumber + ".csv";
    return File(data, "text/csv", filename);
}
```

Now in order to invoke this action and have the user be prompted for download simply create a link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download csv", "Download", new { accnumber = "123" })
```

or if you are using a form:

```
@Html.BeginForm("Download", "SomeController")
{
    @Html.TextBox("accnumber")
    <input type="submit" value="Download CSV" />
}
```

Comment: The reason I use a pop up form is because The users needs to enter an account number before I can generate the the csv. the account number forms part of the account_ref field. the account number is not known until the user enters the account number.

Comment: @uk101man, your problem doesn't come from the fact that you are using a popup form. It comes from the fact that you are submitting this form using AJAX. You shouldn't be doing this. Use a regular `@Html.BeginForm()` helper to generate the form and do not use any AJAX to post it.

Comment: but ajax form is what project awesome uses I believe. When I implement your idea the csv file contents is returned to the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting the form using AJAX has disadvantages. You shouldn't be doing this. I would rather use @Html.BeginForm() helper to generate the form and submit the data using button event.

Hope this helps